# Code deploy appspec.yml permission specification for the pattern match vendor folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket-pipelines, aws-code-deploy

I have below requirement that I need to archive with the AWS code-deploy appspec.yml, I am confused about how to do this, As no matter how I try, the composer/vendor folder/files do not get 755. Any idea on how to solve this?

**1. I want everything (files and folders) in /var/www/html to be owned by nginx AND have permission 644 including folders and files.**

**2. Except "vendor" folder and files inside some modules, so I want to search for the pattern of folder "vendor" and set it to 755.**

My current appsepc.yml is like below

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /apps
    destination: /var/www/html/apps
  - source: /core
    destination: /var/www/html/core
permissions:
  - object: /var/www/html/
    pattern: "**"
    except: [ "./var/*", "*/vendor/*" ]
    owner: nginx
    group: nginx
    mode: 644
    type:
      - file
  - object: /var/www/html/
    pattern: "*/vendor/*"
    owner: nginx
    group: nginx
    mode: 755
```

Comment: Are you really using `appsepc.xml`? This is wrong file extention.

Comment: .yml sorry i meant

Comment: @Marcin any idea of luck with this?

Comment: Sorry. At the moment I don't know.